# What can I do to strengthen my hand?

Tags: weightlifting, injury, hands

About 6 weeks ago, I was doing heavy cleans from the blocks. On the last, my knee lined up with my elbow and forearm, catching the weight and forcing my hand to bend backward. I can use it day to day, but when trying out lifting again a couple of weeks later my finger tips went numb and stayed that way. I have taken another couple of weeks off after 2 weeks back at the gym. Only the end of my thumb still feels some numbness. When I catch something or turn it enough the pain goes through the bottom of my palm through the webbing between my thumb and forefinger in a semicircle.

Any ideas to strengthen or reduce my time away from lifting?

Comment: I think you're in physical therapist land.

Comment: Was hoping to avoid that, but thanks.

Comment: A PT (physical therapist) or OT (occupational therapist) who specialize in hands (hand therapist) are the best ones to advise you.

Comment: The title says "how can I strengthen my hand" but the text says "how can I diagnose and treat a hand injury."

Comment: You've probably damaged a nerve which will take some time to heal. You should probably check with a doctor just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to strengthen your arms, then i can help. I am not going to suggest curls and extensions, but exercises that train the small muscles, that heavy compound movements will not train.
I guess your main problem is with your forearms, so here are two of my favorites

[Palms up wrist curl](http://www.bodybuilding.com/exercises/detail/view/name/palms-up-barbell-wrist-curl-over-a-bench)

[Palms down wrist curl](http://www.bodybuilding.com/exercises/detail/view/name/palms-down-wrist-curl-over-a-bench)

These two exercises are the only ones i personally use to train my forearms, and they are good. You could also just pick up a barbell that has heavy weights on, and just hold it as long as you can. Next time add some weight and do it again, constantly try to do it longer and heavier. My friend swears by it.

Superset(one after another) these two exercises atleast 6x12. Forearms are used a lot daily, so they require a little bit more than other muscle groups. I personally train them twice a week.

I hope this answers your question on how to strenghten your arms.

You should also think about doing some external and internal rotation for the shoulders.
[Exercises can be found here](http://officialbodylastics.eu/pages/bodylastics-eu-clip-exercise-band-systems-shoulder-exercises)

Doing these will help prevent any shoulder injury.

Just a little bonus, just in case.